# JavaFX combo box not showing the selected option

Tags: javafx, combobox

When I select a combo box option the Prompt Text of the cmbo box shows this: [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YL5Lp.png)

Here's the code for setting up the combo box:

```
private void setComboBox(){
    productos_comboPROVEEDOR.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Proveedores>, ListCell<Proveedores>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<Proveedores> call(ListView<Proveedores> p) {
            final ListCell<Proveedores> cell = new ListCell<Proveedores>(){
              @Override
              protected void updateItem(Proveedores t, boolean b){
                  super.updateItem(t,b);
                  if(t!=null){
                      setText(t.getNombre());
                  }else{
                      setText(null);
                  }
            } 
          };
            return cell;
     }

    });
     productos_comboPROVEEDOR.setItems(observableListProv);

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pojo class return object of it,So Put toString() method in your pojo(Proveedores) class and return String value that you have set in combobox.

In below way

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return nombre;
}
```